# Dynamically change UITableView cell separator line color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uicolor

Can anyone give sample code how to change the UITableView cell separator line color dynamically?

Comment: what line are you talking about ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

i assumed asking about tableview seperator color

use switch to all color then like this u can

```
 [tableview setSeparatorColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

OR

Here R, G, B are float for different Color value.

```
 [tableview setSeparatorColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:R green:G blue:B alpha:1]];
```

Often I use this below code

```
 [tableview setSeparatorColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:190/255.0f green:195.0/255.0f blue:199.0/255.0f alpha:1]];
```